# Can we let people customize a new database via web by using MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb

My understanding of the mongoDB development is usually

1. Creating a model file, specific about how the data's entities should be, like username, email ...
2. user can input the correspond form and send a POST request then utilize mongoose to create correspond datas.

**But I am wondering can I let the user customize their form and create like a data standard in mongoDB ?**

1. User create a form they want to and generate a POST request
2. Generate a new database in MongoDB
3. Other people can fill out the form and send a POST request

Is that possible , or I should definitely define the dataset first ?

Comment: MongoDB does not require any schema at all. In principle every document can be different.

Comment: You are probably thinking about working with a specific tool (like Mongoose) where you define a fixed schema. You can use the native NodeJS Driver APIs to not use any fixed schema. But, there is an _option_ called as Schema Validation, in case you need to define a schema upfront.